# Best way to find HTML and CSS version

Tags: html, css, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I want to know the HTML and CSS version of a website/webapplication ?

Comment: What do you mean by *without seeing the code*?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by html/css *version*?

Comment: sorry edited question

Comment: We have versions like HTML 4.1 or 5 right? I want to know how we can find versions for html and css, for a website/webapplication

Comment: that answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

By HTML *version* I assume you mean the doc type.  That can be retrieved using the following line of javascript:

```
console.log(document.doctype);
```

CSS, however, doesn't have *versions* in the sense that a version can be declared in the document.  Rather, if a style declaration is supported (i.e, the browser can interpret it) then it gets rendered.  Terms like CSS3/CSS2.1/Etc are just names we use to describe the state of accepted style declarations in a given generation.  They're not bound to some kind of identifiable *version* that a browser can explicitly detect.

So the short answer is that CSS version is dictated by the styles you include in your stylesheet, and CSS support is dictated by the browser you use to view your website.

Tools like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) will help you detect what your browser does and does not support.